# jQuery ajax post data to form mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make jQuery post some data to an PHP form mail via Ajax, so i can sent the data in an email.
But my problem is that it doesn't post anything in the mail. It's empty.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#food_requirements').hide();
  $('#name_allergy').hide();
  $('#food').click(function(e) {
    $('#food_requirements').fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $('#allergy').click(function(e) {
    $('#name_allergy').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('.confirm input').click(function(e) {
    $(".confirm").removeClass('red-border');
  });
  $('.checkin').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", 'images/loader.gif');
    var checkBoxs = document.getElementsByName("confirmation");
    var confirmation = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxs.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxs[i].checked) {
        confirmation += checkBoxs[i].value + " - ";
      }
    }
    if (confirmation == '') {
      $('.confirm').addClass('red-border');
      $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
      return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("food").checked) {
      var food = "yes";
    } else {
      var food = "no";
    }
    var food_requirements = $('#food_requirements').val();
    if (food == 'yes') {
      if (food_requirements == '') {
        $('#food_requirements').addClass('red-border');
        $('#food_requirements').focus();
        $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
        return false;
      } else {
        $("#food_requirements").removeClass('red-border');
      }
    }
    if (document.getElementsByName("allergy").checked) {
      var allergy = "yes";
    } else {
      var allergy = "no";
    }
    var name_allergy = $('#name_allergy').val();
    if (allergy == 'yes') {
      if (name_allergy == '') {
        $('#name_allergy').addClass('red-border');
        $('#name_allergy').focus();
        $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
        return false;
      } else {
        $("#name_allergy").removeClass('red-border');
      }
    }
    var firstname1 = $('#firstname1').val();
    if (firstname1 == '') {
      $('#firstname1').addClass('red-border');
      $('#firstname1').focus();
      $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#firstname1").removeClass('red-border');
    }
    var lastname1 = $('#lastname1').val();
    if (lastname1 == '') {
      $('#lastname1').addClass('red-border');
      $('#lastname1').focus();
      $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#lastname1").removeClass('red-border');
    }
    var age1 = $('#age1').val();
    if (age1 == '') {
      $('#age1').addClass('red-border');
      $('#age1').focus();
      $(this).attr("src", 'images/checkin.jpg');
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#age1").removeClass('red-border');
    }
    var fname = "";
    var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname");
    for (var i = 0; i < firstname.length; i++) {
      if (firstname[i].value != '') {
        if (firstname[i].value != '') fname += firstname[i].value + " / ";
      }
    }
    var lname = "";
    var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname");
    for (var i = 0; i < lastname.length; i++) {
      if (lastname[i].value != '') lname += lastname[i].value + " / ";
    }
    var ages = "";
    var age = document.getElementsByName("age");
    for (var i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
      if (age[i].value != '') ages += age[i].value + " / ";
    }










    var data = "&confirmation=Events: " + confirmation + "&firstname=First names: " + fname + "&lastname=Last names: " + lname + "&age=Ages: " + ages;
        if (food_requirements != '') data = data + "&food_requirements=Food requirements: " + food_requirements;
        if (name_allergy != '') data = data + "&allergy=Allergy: " + name_allergy;
        var url = "rsvp.php";
        $('#form').html('Your CHECK-IN is done!.<br/> Thank you very much.');
        $.post(url, data, function(msg) {
          $('#form').addClass('formfinal');
            alert(data)
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          if (msg.substr(0, 2) == "ok") {
            $('#form').html('Your CHECK-IN is done!.<br/> Thank you very much.');
          } else {
            $('#form').html('There has been an error with the CHECK-IN. Please try again.');
            return false;
          }
        });





  });
});
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
function addguest() {
  $("#guests").append("<input class='firstname' name='firstname' placeholder='First Name' /><input class='lastname' name='lastname' placeholder='Last Name' /><input class='age' name='age' placeholder='Age' /><div class='clr'></div>");
}
```

I get this value when i alert "data"

"&confirmation=Events:Bollywood - &firstname=First names: andreas / john / james / &lastname=Last names: Johnson / Jamesson / Hansen / &age= Ages: 24 / 26 / 42 / &food_requirements=Food requirements: Does it work"

This is my php(rsvp.php) form. I've tried some different stuff just to get some sort of value, but without any luck. I just receive an empty email.

```
<?php
   $email = 'from@mail.com';
   $message = 'firstname' . $firstname . '';
   $to = 'me@mail.com';
   mail($to, 'my subject', $message, $email);
?>
```

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: In your ajax call you do not seem to have any parameters named fname or data, yet in you PHP script you are trying to retrieve data from those. And in your PHP, even though you do not define $fname, you use it to construct $message.

Answer (score 1):

the Problem is here 
you expecting $firstname = $_POST['fname']; but passing firstname

```
var data = "&confirmation=Events: " + confirmation + "&firstname=First names: " + fname + "&lastname=Last names: " + lname + "&age=Ages: " + ages;
```

Comment: Thanks Volkinc. I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work. It still doesn't write any value in the mail?

Here is what my PHP look like now:

<?php
$email = 'from@mail.com';
$message = 'firstname' . $firstname . '';
$to = 'me@mail.com';

mail($to, 'my subject', $message, $email);
?>

Comment: mail("me@mail.com", 'my subject', "my message"); //try the hardcoded version? will you get something?

Comment: hi. mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message ,$additional_headers ) , so, the forth parameter is a headers, so try only with first three